# How to display a html source code saved inside a <code></code> tag of external / shared location page in my local html page?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a shared external HTML file, inside that html file : a full html source code has written inside a `<code>` tag. Please help me to read that html source code inside the `<code></code>` tag and display it in another html file which i need to save in my system locally.

there will be changes in html source code inside the `<code>` tag, so without referring there i need to load the html source code in my page load, automatically.

how can i make it possible

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+get+content+tag+other+site+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Hi! If you're looking to retrieve some data (i.e. the text, not the rendered HTML) on the page load, the `window.onload` function ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event)) might be what you're looking for.

If you instead want to render the other page, maybe an iframe could be a solution ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)).

I'm not too sure what exactly you want to achieve. Consider providing a minimal example with some code to illustrate your problem :)